# Add Internal Borders but not external

Tags: html, css

I have a grid of square images.
I want to put a border on the inside of each of these but not on the outside of the whole box, as in the image below:

[image]

Here's the html setup.

```
<div class="grid-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="[image url]" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.grid-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.grid-wrapper ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
}
.grid-wrapper ul li {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
}
```

I've tried putting the border all the way round each of the `li` elements and then adding a white border on the `grid-wrapper` to put it over the outer borders but that didn't work.

How can I get this without manually setting each one's `border-left`/`border-bottom` etc. The squares are dynamically pulled from the database so each one doesn't have a particular class, they're all identical.

**UPDATE**

The grid is fluid. When you pull the browser window open, it adds more to the top row (if there's room) and less when you pull the browser window inward. There's no fixed number of icons.

Comment: Please include your attempt(s) and what specifically didn't work.

Comment: Please show us your CSS

Comment: @showdev As I mentioned, I tried putting a border around the li elements and then adding a white border around the grid-wrapper. I'll clarify: The border around the grid-wrapper did not appear on-top, but rather just appeared alongside each of the inner element borders.

Comment: @oGeez I've just added my CSS as it stands currently.

Comment: @danielhanly.com - Can you plz create a fiddle with at least 2 rows and 2 columns?

Comment: The CSS code you supplied does not seem to relate to your HTML. Also, is your grid a fixed or flexible width? Does the number of items per row change based on the width of the browser?

Comment: Your css does not match your html.. `grid-wrapper` or `client-wrapper` ?

Comment: @showdev my attempts at clarifying the classes for this example weren't matched on my css. I didn't think clients was very descriptive ;) It's all matching now. I'll work on that fiddle.

Comment: It looks like the border is around the padding of the LI elements as they should be. Are you trying to place the border around the image inside the LI padding? If so add a ul.client-list li img rule

Comment: is it always 5 in each row or will this vary?

Comment: @Huangism it will vary. I'll clarify in my original question now.

Comment: You'll need to write some javascript for this if you want it fluid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what you want to happen when there's a ragged row at the bottom, so I'm not sure if this meets your requirement fully, but this example may accomplish what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/52LRd/

It works by setting a border on the bottom and left each of each element, then by budging the ul inside the wrapper 1px up and left, making those edges invisible.

```
.grid-wrapper {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-wrapper ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    right: 1px;
}
.grid-wrapper ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
    border-left: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
}
```

This gets you out of having to try to figure out which list items are in the top row, bottom row, left column, and right column, which would require JavaScript.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I was hoping for a solution that was just CSS & HTML. JS is good, but for such minor things, I wouldn't want to go down that route.

Comment: Absolutely. If this meets your needs, it keeps things much simpler.